# How to place two div's one below the other in polymer app-header

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

How to place another div below the `<div main-title>My App</div>` such that the content in second div should come below the content in first div.

```
<app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <div main-title>My App</div>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping  in another div that has display block.

Like this:

```
<div style="display:block;">
    <div main-title>My App</div>
    <div other-div>Something</div>
</div>
```